# Comparing the performance speed for both bmat and hstack

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I am trying to compare the speed for both bmat and hstack when comes to concatenating coordinate matrices which are huge.

My code:

```
from scipy.sparse import bmat, coo_matrix, hstack
import timeit

import numpy as np

a = np.add(*np.indices((1000,1000)))

A = coo_matrix(a)
B = coo_matrix(a)

t = timeit.timeit("hstack([A,B]).toarray()", "from __main__ import A, B, hstack", number= 2000)
print(t)

tt = timeit.timeit("bmat([[A,B]])", "from __main__ import A, B, bmat", number = 2000)
print(tt)
```

From my experiment, it seems like bmat has faster processing speed comparing to hstack.

```
85.89499111475607
71.0423545148451
```

I would like to know whether my testing approach is correct or is there anything that makes hstack performed better when the coo_matrix are huge? Should I use bmat or hstack, from the experiment, it seems like bmat is better to use but I would like to know the differences.

Comment: Because you not run this in RTOS, you will need average data by time, for example you must run t = timeit.timeit("hstack([A,B]).toarray()", "from __main__ import A, B, hstack", number= 2000) 100 times and run tt = timeit.timeit("bmat([[A,B]])", "from __main__ import A, B, bmat", number = 2000) 100 times too. Next you divide result by 100 and get more appropriate results

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion. I will do it and also to check more about RTOS. I missed RTOS and didnt notice all this time I am doing experiments and analysis not based on RTOS. I will check more about it. Appreciated if you could share more about where I should start with RTOS